# Why does trying to present an MFMailComposeViewController here lock up the screen?

Tags: ios, ipad, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have an iPad application, composed of a root view controller that loads a second view controller. Within that second view controller, I have one button that should present an `MFMailComposeViewController`.

My Problem is:
**On the Simulator, this works fine**. However, **on actual device**, *pressing this button locks up the screen and seems to disable all user interaction with the interface*.

My Code is:

```
//************** Send Email using Default IM ************************
-(void) showEmailModalView
{
    NSLog(@"Start method <ExportStatisticsController> : <showEmailModalView>  --");


    //    emailTextField.text = [emailTextField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(null)" withString:@""];
    //    subjectTextField.text = [subjectTextField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(null)" withString:@""];
    //    messageBodyTextView.text = [messageBodyTextView.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(null)" withString:@""];

    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self; // &lt;- very important step if you want feedbacks on what the 
    //user did with your email sheet

    [picker setSubject:@""];

    NSArray *torec=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"xyz@company.com", nil];
    [picker setToRecipients:torec];
    [torec release];

//------ message body ---

    NSString *body =@"";

    [picker setMessageBody:body isHTML:NO]; // depends. Mostly YES, unless you want to send it as plain text (boring)

    picker.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack; // choose your style, unfortunately, Translucent colors behave quirky.
//    picker.ModalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
    NSLog(@"End method <ExportStatisticsController> : <showEmailModalView>  --");

}
```

**What** could I be doing wrong to cause a screen freeze like this?

Comment: Don't know whats the point of creating the exact same question when the previous one was closed...

Comment: There are many spelling mistake and confused words.so i try to make it more clear. If it is clear than previous please tell me.

Comment: Have your checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987703/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-ipad)?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for modification.

Answer (score 0):

The device is probably not set up to send mail.

Before using the `MFMailComposeViewController` you should call `[MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]` to ensure that the device is configured to send mail.

It's probably a good idea too to check that your `picker` variable is non-nil before trying to present it as a modal view controller.